# How to get the URL to fully reload each time?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Issue: appears to be that banno framework is "remembering" the urls. This is happening in a mobile browser when the user does not close the tab or browser. When the user opens the page, banno is remembering the url from last time and trying to load the same url.
What needs to happen is that banno needs to fully reload the page so that we can go retrieve a new url and log the user in again.
Could it be how they treat plugins when a browser is left open. A url that is loaded is not good forever.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are good that the situation you're encountering is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71267143/6680761

Essential info from that link is:

> Part of keeping state of the page is keeping authentication data. The OAuth flow used to initially authenticate the user is not intended to be used on every page refresh. It's expected that the embedded web application will keep its own authentication state. How this is done is usually very specific to the language and platform used for the embedded web application. However all strategies almost exclusively use a cookie which is destroyed when the application closes.

> The Oauth callback URL with an authentication code should be redirected away from once the code is exchanged for an access token. From that point forward your app should be using its own authentication mechanism.